# Adding connection points to groups

Tags: draw.io

with styles it is possible to add connection points to a shape (points = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]...[Draw.IO help](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042498-how-to-add-remove-connection-points-how-to-connect-anywhere-on-a-shape-)). I tried this for groups, but it does not work. Is there a way to create connection points on groups? Or do I have to create a more complex shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible at the moment but feel free to add a feature request here: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues

Regards,